# Can I export filtered data from Power BI Embedded report programmatically?

Tags: javascript, c#, azure, export, powerbi-embedded

I'm looking for ability to export data with filters applied by user programmatically.

I know that there is the JavaScript API for interact with iframes but cannot find functions to do export

Comment: why you did not export data directly from source?

Comment: @CuongLe because I'm storing some sensitive information on my own server

Answer (score 0):

Recently added Export functionality allows you to get a visual's data.

```js
visual.exportData(models.ExportDataType.Summarized /* can be Underlying */, numOfRows)
  .then(function (data) {
    Log.log(data);
  })
  .catch(function (errors) {
    Log.log(errors);
  });
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Export-Data